# integer surgeries on knots

Tags: 3-manifolds, knot-theory

I have constructed a list of surgery coefficients which yield spherical space forms. For instance, there are two knots with different Alexander polynomials on which 29-surgery will give a small Seifert fibered space of $S^2(2,3,5)$-type. Now I am just wondering does anyone know any knot on which 58 or 83 surgery will give a spherical space form. I would appreciate any help very much.

Answer (score 9):

Lens spaces of orders 58 and 83 may be obtained by integral surgeries on torus knot; see Moser's "[Elementary surgeries on torus knots](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-38/issue-3/Elementary-surgery-along-a-torus-knot/pjm/1102969920.full)" which gives the classification up to homeomorphism. (Mind Moser's conventions.)

More specifically:

58/1 surgery on the (3,19)-torus knot yields the lens space L(58,-9), and

83/1 surgery on the (2,41)-torus knot yields the lens space L(83,-4).

Here I'm using the convention that -p/q surgery on the unknot yields the lens space L(p,q) so that +5/1 surgery on (2,3)-torus knot yields L(5,-4).

Edit: Of course any non-zero surgery on unknot is spherical, but I reckon you were looking for something less trivial.